# lifetime of an object managed by const std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I see below notes in [`std::unique_ptr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> Only non-const `unique_ptr` can transfer the ownership of the managed object to another `unique_ptr`. The lifetime of an object managed by const `std::unique_ptr` is limited to the scope in which the pointer was created.

Is there anyone who can explain it with an example? I could not figure it out why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply can not move from a `const std::unique_ptr` and you can't use other modifying member functions - `swap`, `release` and `reset` either (these are logically non-const qualified, cannot be called on a `const` instance).

Transferring ownership implies resetting the old owner to non-owning state, thus modifying it.

---

<sup>`const std::unique_ptr` will manage *at most* one object during its lifetime (starting from its initialization).
In case of `std::unique_ptr const&`, you won't be able to transfer ownership from the referenced (even non-const) `std::unique_ptr` through this reference (const correctness).</sup>

Comment: ahh, actually it's fully about const. I see. Thanks.

Comment: What did you think it'd be about? :)

Comment: I focus too much on lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

The `reset`, `release`, `swap`, and move assignment functions are non-const member functions and therefore cannot be used with a const instance of the `std::unique_ptr` class. Therefore, a `const std::unique_ptr` has no way of being modified and is forced to own the pointer until it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you can transfer ownership of a managed object to another `unique_ptr` by using move assignment or the move constructor, e.g.:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(1));
std::unique_ptr<int> q(std::move(p)); 
//now q owns the pointer, which is freed when q is destructed
```

But if `p` was `const`, you wouldn't be able to do so, and the managed object will be freed when `p` is destructed:

```
const std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(1));
std::unique_ptr<int> q(std::move(p));  //compilation error
```

Answer (score 2):

A unique_ptr owns the memory that it points at.

```
void MyFunc()
{ 
    // Creates a unique pointer that points at a Foo object.
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();

    // ... do some stuff, then return
}
```

In this example, we create a Foo object and assign it to our `unique_ptr`. Normally when you create something that's on the heap, you have to use `new` allocate space for it in the heap and construct it, and `delete` to destruct it and deallocate its space. Here, the `unique_ptr` handles deallocation as soon as you leave the scope where the `unique_ptr` was created (which in this case is the end of the function).

> Only non-const unique_ptr can transfer the ownership of the managed object to another unique_ptr.

This means you can transfer the ownership of your pointer to a different `unique_ptr`, but only if it's not marked as const. Only one `unique_ptr` can own an object at a time.

One way to do that would be like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo1 = std::make_unique<Foo>();
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo2 = std::move(foo1);
```

Now the pointer in `foo1` has been moved to `foo2`. `foo1` is no longer managing that memory, `foo2` is.

> The lifetime of an object managed by const std::unique_ptr is limited to the scope in which the pointer was created.

This means that when your unique_ptr leaves scope, it deletes the object that it points to. It's as if you did this:

```
void MyFunc()
{ 
    Foo* foo = new Foo()

    // ... do some stuff, then return

    delete foo;
}
```

The benefit is that now you don't have to manually call delete, which is good because that's a potential memory leak if you forget to delete it.